# Is it safe to remove the SQL Server 2005 Express installed by Visual Studio 2008 when SQL Server 2008 is installed?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Or will everything explode and kill a couple of kittens?

Comment: +1 for the best potential error I have heard of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. The engines are isolated from each other, so, you can run both in parallel or remove/uninstall components if you need.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

That should be safe.

What we have had problems with is: if we install SQL Express first, then the management console will not install, when you install SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I had kitten parts splattered everywhere when I tried to do exactly what you are asking about.  So I burned it all down and reinstalled, installing SQL Server 2008 first, and then making sure to de-select the database components in the Visual Studio installations.

So far so good, but my SQL Server installation is used sparingly.

Comment: I'm sure you had the kitten parts, but I uninstalled SQL 2005 and then installed 2008 and so far, all kittens are safe and sound.